# Specifying Room dimensions in networked-a-frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am new to a-frame and have followed the examples of haydenjameslee networked-aframe. I was wondering if there is a way to specify the room size when defining the a-scene in it's tag

```
<a-scene networked-scene="app: myApp; room: room1;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround, for I don't fully understand how the component works.
I found there is a player list under the reference `NAF.entities.entities`
I made a component attached to the scene:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo',{
  init:function(){
    setTimeout(function(){   
      console.log(Object.keys(NAF.entities.entities));
      console.log(Object.keys(NAF.entities.entities)[0]);
      console.log(Object.keys(NAF.entities.entities).length);
    },5000);
  }
});
```

The first log gives me an array of the players id's.
The second one gives the id of the first element. 
The last gives me the number of the players.

You can check for the number of players on load, and if the number is exceeded, just deny access, change the room, or href to a 'lobby' website.

 Working glitch here: glitch.com/edit/#!/sudden-antler

---

Of course instead of waiting 5 seconds i should be listening to a loaded event, I'll look into it once im not so busy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible in A-Frame. 
What do you need it for?

Comment: I want to create a room and put posters on the wall. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score -2):

An NPM Package aframe-room-component is available that easily lets you create rooms and connects them. Serves my need.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-room-component

It can be used as follows

```
<rw-room position="-3 0 -5" material="color:#787">
      <rw-floor material="color:red"></rw-floor>
      <rw-ceiling material="color:blue"></rw-ceiling>
      <rw-wall position="6 0 0" material="color:yellow"></rw-wall>
      <rw-wall position="6 0 6" material="color:green"></rw-wall>
      <rw-wall position="0 0 6" material="color:brown"></rw-wall>
      <rw-wall position="0 0 0" material="color:pink"></rw-wall>
    </rw-room>
```